# Django composite Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, model

I have a table called "Tickets" and exact copy of this same table called "Logs" .The aim is to copy every data into "Logs"  . So to keep the structure same I need to exclude Django default generated field "id" and planned to use a composite key with field name "ticket_no" and  "updated_on".
is there any way to make these field as primary key without this 'id'.

Comment: Django has no composite *primary* key no.

Comment: Serialise it and store it as Json data on your `Log` model?